# 'No reachable servers' error when beginning parse migration with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, ibm-cloud, database-migration, compose-db

I am in the process of migrating my app from Parse to MongoDB and IBM Bluemix, however I can't seem to reach the server when attempting the migration of data from Parse.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/02/01/migrating-from-parse-to-bluemix/) tutorial, and I am currently on the step: **Migrating data from Parse.com to your MongoDB instance**

I am currently getting this error: `No reachable servers` when clicking 'Begin the migration'.

These are the connection strings in compose:

[image]

And I have tried entering various strings. I assumed this would work:

```
mongodb://username:password@aws-us-east-1-portal.7.dblayer.com:10803/mtcdatabase
```

But I get the same error. Obviously I'm changing `username` and `password` to my own credentials.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Well is the port open on the server? Are you able to connect from any other point? The error message should be pretty descriptive in that it is "unreachable". So it's either not running or cannot be reached due to some other consideration, such as firewall rules. Also not really a programming question, and neither is the likely solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was using the latest version of MongoDB, however Parse doesn't seem to support it. Therefore, I had to use MongoDB Classic version 3.0. Everything works great now.